# Appending a list by assigning values from another list by changing some elements python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I have a list, and I want to construct another list from this list, by discarding some elements, and changing some elements. I am doing the following:

```
gridAtoms = someFunction() # a list of lists. gridAtoms[i][6] is [float,float,float]
occ = someOtherFunction() # a 3D numpy array

occGridAtoms = []
selectedOcc = []
for i, atom in enumerate(gridAtoms):
    coord = np.array(atom[6])
    x = int(round(b1.dot(coord) / spacing[0]))
    y = int(round(b2.dot(coord) / spacing[1]))
    z = int(round(b3.dot(coord) / spacing[2]))
    selectedOcc.append(occ[x, y, z])
    currentAtom = list(atom)
    currentAtom[7][0] = occ[x, y, z]
    if occ[x, y, z] >= 0.01:
        occGridAtoms.append(list(currentAtom))
```

The problem is, even though I do `currentAtom = list(atom)` instead of just `currentAtom = atom`, the elements of `gridAtom`, specifically, `gridAtom[i][7][0]` change. Why does this happen even though I create a new list by using `list()`? And how can I keep `gridAtoms` unchanged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing `list(<another list>)` just does a shallow copy of the list, not a deep copy, so if the list itself contains mutable objects inside it, those are copied by reference, that is the new list would contain the same references , and any changes inside those mutable objects would reflect accross lists.

Example to show this behavior -

```
>>> l = [[1,2],[3,4]]
>>> newl = list(l)
>>> newl[0][1] = 5
>>> l
[[1, 5], [3, 4]]
```

What you really want to do would be deep copy , in which case you should use , `copy.deepcopy()` , Example -

```
import copy
currentAtom = copy.deepcopy(atom)
```

Example/Demo -

```
>>> l = [[1,2],[3,4]]
>>> import copy
>>> newl = copy.deepcopy(l)
>>> newl[0][1] = 5
>>> l
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

Comment: Oh, ok. So if `l` had been a 1d list, it would have been ok, right?

Comment: yes, if it were a 1d list of immutable objects (like ints/floats/strings, etc), `list()` would have been enough. If the 1d list again contained some mutable object, like instances of some custom class or some other object , then again you could have had issues there.